# Cambio de innerHTML a appendChild

Tags: javascript

tengo una pregunta, aprendi a usar el innerHTML y funciona, crea toda la data que tengo el el json y la renderiza en el HTML, pero no se como cambiarlo por appendChild,estuve viendo algunos ejemplos pero vi cosas muy sencillas como agregar un h1 o un p pero aca como son varios elementos no supe como hacerlo,me dijeron que no usara mas el innerHTML, envió el código, de antemano gracias, otra cosa los datos los estoy trayendo de un .json:

el json no me dejo agregarlo pero realmente solo me interesan las imagenes:

[
{
"codigo": 1,
"img": "./images/f1.png",
"name": "Product1",
"description": "Productuno"
},

{
"codigo": 2,
"img": "./images/f2.png",
"name": "Product2",
"description": "Productdos"
},

]

```js
let products = document.querySelector(".row");
import data from "../data.json" assert { type: "json" };

data.map(product => {

  products.innerHTML +=
    `<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="img-box">
       <img src="${product.img}" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="detail-box">
        <h5>${product.description}</h5>
        <div class="price_box">
          <h6 class="price_heading">
            <span>$</span> 100.00
          </h6>
          <a href="">Buy Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
 
});
```

```css
.pagination-container {
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   /* position: absolute;*/
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .pagination-number,
  .pagination-button{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    margin: 0.25rem 0.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    border-radius: .2rem;
  }
  
  .pagination-number:hover,
  .pagination-button:not(.disabled):hover {
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .pagination-number.active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #0085b6;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
     
    </div>
```

Comment: podes usar los metodos document.createElement() y document.createDocumentFragment(). Una vez creados los nodos usas append child sobre ellos para anidarlos. Podes agregar el resto de tu codigo (html css y json) para que sea mas facil que te ayuden.

Comment: Pero en createElement si deja agregar asi como en innerHTML con el += ? y despues todo el código html.

El css es bastante porque esta con bootstrap, voy a agregar lo del json

Comment: nono, es diferente al inner html, no podes concatenar usando +=

Comment: esa es mi duda, no se como añadir los divs que ya tienen clases creadas y dentro de cada div las etiquetas html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahi te paso una solucion, tengo que crear los nodos uno por uno, modificarles las propiedades y agregandoles las clases que necesitan (lo que es bastante tedioso la verdad), al final pongo los nodos dentro de otros con append() y appendChild():

```
data.map(product => {
  // creando los nodos y agregando sus clases y propiedades manualmente:
  let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); // fragmento con cada div contenedor del producto (no ocupa un nodo en el documento)
  let container = document.createElement("DIV");
  container.classList.add("col-md-6", "col-lg-4");
  let subcontainer = document.createElement("DIV")
  subcontainer.classList.add("box")
  let imgbox = document.createElement("DIV")
  imgbox.classList.add("img-box");
  let detailbox = document.createElement("DIV")
  detailbox.classList.add("detail-box");
  let img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.src = product.img;
  let desc = document.createElement("H5");
  desc.textContent = product.description;
  let pricebox = document.createElement("DIV")
  pricebox.classList.add("price_box")
  let priceheading = document.createElement("H6");
  priceheading.classList.add("price_heading")
  let link = document.createElement("A");
  link.textContent = "Buy Now"
  let span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  span.textContent = "$"
  let price = document.createTextNode("' 100.00 '") // nodo de texto

  // finalmente anidamos todos los nodos y tenemos un resultado equivalente a innerHTML
  priceheading.append(span, price);
  pricebox.append(priceheading, link);
  detailbox.append(desc, pricebox);
  imgbox.appendChild(img);
  subcontainer.append(imgbox, detailbox);
  container.appendChild(subcontainer);
  fragment.appendChild(container);
  products.appendChild(fragment);

  // La diferencia entre append y appendChild es que el primero nos permite anidar mas de un nodo a la vez y tambien permite nodos de texto
  // appendChild solo permite 1 elemento y no puede ser Textnode.
});
```

Un detalle: deberias usar forEach no map, ya que map devuelve algo que no estas usando.

Comment: Gracias probe todo lo que me enviaste y me funciono, ahora debo estudiarlo mas para poder entenderlo bien, también hice el cambio del map por foreach, segun habia leido map era como actualización de foreach

Comment: @PupoXws pensa que cada nodo es una etiqueta que yo necesite al que yo le puedo cambiar las propiedades y agregarles clases como quiera. Pero para que se renderizen en la pantalla debo hacerlos hijos de algun elemento dentro del DOM (hacer un appendChild), aunque sea del body. Despues hay otro tipo de nodos que son los textnodes que no son etiquetas sino texto plano.